# General solution of $\dot{x} = (t+x) / (t-x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following question: I need to find the general solution of $\dot{x} = (t+x) / (t-x)$. I tried to use the substitution $x = y \cdot t$ to get:
\begin{align*}
\dot{(y \cdot t)} &= \dot{y}t + y = \frac{t + ty}{t - ty} = \frac{1 + y}{1 - y} \\
\dot{y}t &= \frac{1 + y}{1 - y} - y \\
\dot{y}t &= \frac{1 + y - y + y^2}{1 - y} \\
\dot{y} &= \frac{1 + y^2}{(1 - y)t} \\
\int_{y_0}^y \frac{1-\xi}{1 + \xi^2}d\xi &= \int_{t_0}^t 1/\eta \; d \eta \\\end{align*}
$$
\arctan(y) - \arctan(y_0) - \frac{\ln(1+ y^2)}{2} + \frac{\ln(1 + y_0^2)}{2} = \ln |t| - \ln |t_0|
$$
However, I have no idea how to solve this equation for $y$. There is probably a much better way to do it than what I did, could someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that it is correct, I just need to make the change with the variable x and that's it. You can see here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%3D%28t%2Bx%29%2F%28t-x%29 the same solution obtained.

Comment: is this a hw question? did the question ask you to solve for x in terms of t? if not, i think just sub y=x/t to get sn implicit function.

Comment: I don't think an explicit solution is possible, whether for $x$ or $t.$

Comment: You can absorb all your constants (the second, fourth, and sixth terms) into a single constant for simplicity. Also, your solution is identical with the solution Mathematica provides, if that's any comfort.